# sed or grep or awk to match very very long lines

Tags: sed

more file

param1=" 1,deerfntjefnerjfntrjgntrjnvgrvgrtbvggfrjbntr*rfr4fv*frfftrjgtrignmtignmtyightygjn      2,3,4,5,6,7,8,
rfcmckmfdkckemdio8u548384omxc,mor0ckofcmineucfhcbdjcnedjcnywedpeodl40fcrcmkedmrikmckffmcrffmrfrifmtrifmrifvysdfn"

need to match the content of $param1 in the file
but its not work for example
sed -n "/$param1/p" file
or any grep $param1 file etc...

any other solutions? maybe with perl?

Comment: Please post the complete, exact script or command line you are using, along with the exact input & output, and explain what you expected. Then we can probably help.

Comment: for example grep -w $param1 file when file content: 1,deerfntjefnerjfntrjgntrjnvgrvgrtbvggfrjbntr*rfr4fv*frfftrjgtrignmtignmtyightygjn 2,3,4,5,6,7,8, rfcmckmfdkckemdio8u548384omxc,mor0ckofcmineucfhcbdjcnedjcnywedpeodl40fcrcmkedmrikmckffmcrffmrfrifmtrifmrifvysdfn 

_______and param1 is: param1=" 1,deerfntjefnerjfntrjgntrjnvgrvgrtbvggfrjbntr*rfr4fv*frfftrjgtrignmtignmtyightygjn 2,3,4,5,6,7,8, rfcmckmfdkckemdio8u548384omxc,mor0ckofcmineucfhcbdjcnedjcnywedpeodl40fcrcmkedmrikmckffmcrffmrfrifmtrifmrifvysdfn"

Comment: @yael:Please edit your answer, rather than posting a comment. That's what the "edit" button under the answer is for :-).

Answer (score 0):

Hard to help without the exact script you are running, but one point to check:

The value for "param1" that you posted contains asterisk characters ("*"). These have special meaning to sed and grep (and perl, and generally in any regular expression). To match these as literal characters, you usually need to "escape" them by prepending a backslash.

So instead of "aa*b" you'd need "aa*b". Try this first to see if it helps.

Caveat: The shell will also process a \, so when using it as a parameter value put the value into '', as:

```
param1='basldafsd\*asdfsadf'
```

The '' will protect special chars from the shell.